# SQL Count multiple values in one squery

Tags: sql, count

| Order No | Staff1 | Staff2 | Staff3 | Staff4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | Mary |  |  |
| 2 | Sam | Tom |  |  |
| 3 | Sam |  |  |  |
| 4 | Tom | Mary | Sam |  |

How can I count on staff to appear in table ?

Example:

Sam appears in table 3 times

Tom appears in table 1 time

I don't know how to count this table when Staff1 - Staff4 which have "Sam"

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. (I.e. a [mcve].) Also add a tag for the dbms used, to get accurate attention and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use UNION ALL as per my knowledge.

```
SELECT IF(Staff != '', Staff, 'Total') AS Staff, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM (
    SELECT Staff1 AS Staff FROM table4 WHERE Staff1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Staff2 AS Staff FROM table4 WHERE Staff2 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Staff3 AS Staff FROM table4 WHERE Staff3 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Staff4 AS Staff FROM table4 WHERE Staff4 IS NOT NULL
) AS StaffData
GROUP BY Staff;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If I need to find out "Sam" by a single query?

Comment: Please check a single query for "Sam" => SELECT 'Sam' AS Staff, SUM( (Staff1 = 'Sam') + (Staff2 = 'Sam') + (Staff3 = 'Sam') + (Staff4 = 'Sam') ) AS Count FROM table4;

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP (and others) which dbms this is for.